# Stackoverflow RSS not binding to Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rss, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
Hi All
```

I m new at kendo mvc3 and trying to read Stackoverflow Rss as my grid model but i couldn't do it. When i use Yahoo rss my project working but not working with Stackoverflow RSS

**RSS links**

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds
http://news.yahoo.com/rss/

**My Controller Function**

```
public static IEnumerable<Rss> GetRssFeed()
        {

            XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("https://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
            var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("entry")
                        select new Rss
                        {
                            Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                            Link = "<a href="+feed.Element("id").Value+">Go To Page</a>",
                            Description = feed.Element("summary").Value
                        };
            return feeds;
        }

public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = GetRssFeed();
            return View(model);
        }
```

****My Partial View ****

```
@model IEnumerable<KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models.Rss>



<div data-role="page" data-title="Aravind's Partial View Test" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
    <div class="grid" style="margin-left: 5px;" id="grid">


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Encoded(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Description).Encoded(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Link).Encoded(false);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()

    )
)

    </div>
</div>
```

**** Model ****

```
 public class Rss
        {
            public string Link { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed contains namespaces, so when selecting the nodes you need to include those namespaces:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
select new Rss
{
    Title = feed.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title").Value,
    Link = "<a href=" + feed.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}id").Value + ">Go To Page</a>",
    Description = feed.Element("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}summary").Value
};
```

You can also put the namespace in a variable:

```
XDocument feedXml = XDocument.Load("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds");
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var feeds = from feed in feedXml.Descendants(ns + "entry")
select new
{
    Title = feed.Element(ns + "title").Value,
    Link = "<a href=" + feed.Element(ns + "id").Value + ">Go To Page</a>",
    Description = feed.Element(ns + "summary").Value
};
```

Also bear in mind that in the links you provided, StackOverflow uses Atom, whereas Yahoo uses RSS which are 2 different standards. You also mentioned that your code worked for Yahoo which is highly unlikely because in RSS there's not even a tag called `<entry>`.

Comment: thanx ns worked
by the way for yahoo elements used title link and description in item tag